# Android market, tracking purchases to devices

Tags: android, google-play

Is it possible to identify an Android device from which a particular Android Market order (ID provided) was filed? ANDROID_ID would do, for example.

There's a `<buyer-id>` element in order notifications that "identifies the buyer uniquely to Google", but there's no info what's its relationship to Google ID, ANDROID_ID or anything of the like.

Or on the contrary, given a paid app on device, is it possible to retrieve the order ID that the app was purchased with?

Comment: Not that I've found, but you can do this with in-app purchases.  I know it's not what you're after, but figured the info wouldn't hurt to share.

Comment: I'll keep those in mind. For now, the question still stands...